# Format input text file strictly using sed

Tags: linux, sed

I have this text file named file.txt with the content bellow:

```
Name,Height,Width,Area,Colour
Rec1,5,10,50,Black
Rec2,8,11,88,Red
Rec3,9,13,117,Red
Rec4,13,16,208,Blue
Rec5,15,17,262,Red
Rec6,17,19,341,Green
Rec7,20,21,430,Black
Rec8,22,23,528,Red
Rec9,25,25,637,Blue
Rec10,27,27,756,Green
Rec11,30,29,885,Black
Rec12,32,31,1023,Blue
Rec13,35,33,1172,Red
Rec14,37,35,1331,Blue
Rec15,40,37,1500,Black
Rec16,42,39,1678,Green
Rec17,45,41,1867,Red
Rec18,47,43,2066,Blue
Rec19,50,45,2275,Black
Rec20,52,47,2493,Red
```

I need to format it to have to output from the attached picture, using a bash script and pretty much only using linux **sed** command

[image]

What I came up with so far:

```
sed -n '/Name/{h}; /Rec/{x; s/,/:/g; s/Height.*$//g; p; x; p}' file.txt
```

Comment: `sed` is a bit overkill for this. Can't you use `awk`

Comment: I know it's a little bit overkill. In the end we can use something else but ideally is to use as much sed as possible. So in the end it has to be a sed solution but of course, if needed, some other tools like awk can be used

Comment: if you already know the headers, you can use capture groups to get all the five columns and use backreferences in replacement section.. for ex: `echo 'a,b' | sed -E 's/([^,]+),([^,]+)/foo:\1\tbaz:\2/'`

Comment: Here's why I've asked to use sed: n some drafts submitted to me for feedback, I'm seeing things such as IFS, for/while/until loops and even grep and awk based solutions. None of these things is the correct way to go about the assignment or are otherwise precluded because the assignment is all about sed only. If this applies to the work you've done so far, please rethink your approach.

Comment: Well the output of that command is nowhere close to the end result from the picture... I already made a bash script that gets me the desired output but it's using while, for and printf but I have to use the sed approach as much as I can

Comment: `ideally is to use as much sed as possible` but.. why?

Comment: Because that’s how the assignment has been formulated

Comment: What's the down vote for?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
sed 1d file.txt | sed -E 's/([^,]+),([^,]+),([^,]+),([^,]+),([^,]+)/Name: \1\tHeight: \2\tWidth: \3\tArea: \4\tColour: \5\t/'
```

Thanks,
Stefan

Comment: Oh boy, you're the man. Thanks a million! Works like a charm!