# Columns not aligning when using sed \t

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I have an input file named rectangle.txt and my aim is to re-format the contents and output it to rectangle_f.txt using only sed commands.

I have managed to format it the content from:

```
Name,Length,Width,Area,Owner
Rec1,9,9,81,Em
Rec2,2,2,4,Soph
(etc...)
```

To look like this:

```
Name: Rec1    Length: 9    Width: 9    Area: 81    Owner: Em
Name: Rec2    Length: 2    Width: 2    Area: 4     Owner: Soph
```

My issue is when it comes to names with double digits (example: Sq10) the tab that I have inserted between Name and Length is one space too long. For example:

```
Name: Rec9    Length: 6    Width: 6    Area: 36    Owner: Jay
Name: Rec10    Length: 7     Width: 7     Area: 49    Owner: Chris
```

Does anyone know the best way to make all columns line up?
The code I currently have is:

```
 sed -e "1d" \
        -e 's/^/Name: /;s/,/ \t\tHeight: /;s/,/ \t\tWidth: /;s/,/\t\tArea: /;s/,/ \t\tColour: /' rectangle.txt > rectangle_f.txt
```

I need it to apply only to Rec10 to Rec20 (inclusive) which also are code lines 10-20.
Any help would be great!

Comment: seems very similar to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61870873/format-input-text-file-strictly-using-sed

Comment: I'm not sure if sed can properly do the alignment, because there's no built-in way to calculate length and take action accordingly.. if you are allowed to use another command, then you can do something like `echo 'a,b' | sed -E 's/([^,]+),([^,]+)/foo:\1|baz:\2/' | column -t -s'|'`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```sh
sed 1d file.txt | sed -E 's/([^,]+),([^,]+),([^,]+),([^,]+),([^,]+)/Name: \1\tLength: \2\tWidth: \3\tArea: \4\tOwner: \5\t/'
```